# Update $scope on controller from a module when a function is called on another controller in another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Say I have a webapplication which has 4 components. As in there's a left navigation/sidebar with links to those 4 components, and whenever I click on one of them the main content div gets updated with the view of that  component (ui-view). Now I'd like to update the titlebar on top of the page whenever I change to another component. The titlebar is part of the following module (which is the module that's being used at the  tag / it loads all the other modules):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sycf', [
    'ngResource',
    'ui.router',
    'sycf.booksModule',
    'sycf.gamesModule',
    'sycf.moviesModule',
    'sycf.tvModule',
    'sycf.appRoutes'
]);

angular.module('sycf').controller('sycfCtrl', function ($scope,titleService){
    $scope.title = titleService.get();
});

angular.module('sycf').factory('titleService', function () {
    var title = '';

    return {
        set: function (newTitle) {
            console.log("Setting new title.");
            title = newTitle;
        },
        get: function () {
            console.log("Getting new title.");
            return title;
        }
    }
});
```

And as you can see I've tried solving it with a service. In another controller (in a different module) I use titleService.set("something") whenever the controller for a component gets loaded.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sycf.booksModule', ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'sycf']);

angular.module('sycf.booksModule').controller('bookCtrl', function ($scope, titleService) {
    $scope.book = "Brave New World"; //testvalue

    titleService.set("Books");
});
```

Now I don't know how I can make it so the titleService.get(); in the sycfCtrl gets called everytime I move to another view (click on another component in the sidebar/navigation menu).

Or there might just be an entirely different way which might make this a lot easier.

Comment: Could you share the html for your title bar component? I think I may have a much easier way to do this.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZSL06Myb

The tags are core elements from [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-toolbar.html).

[This](http://pastebin.com/t1LbYwMK) is the entire index.html code.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options.

1. Change the title tag to call a function that retrieves the title directly:

   ```
   <div flex>{{getTitle()}}</div>
   ```

   Add to your controller:

   ```
   $scope.getTitle = function() {
       return titleService.get();
   }
   ```
2. Don't use a title service at all, but include the template for the title bar in each view's page. You can do this by making a custom directive where you can set the title and include this directive on each view's template. It might look something like:

   ```
   angular.module('sycf').directive('titleBar',
       function() {
           return {
               restrict: 'EA',
               scope: {
                   title: '@'
               },
               templateUrl: 'path/to/title.html'
           };
        });
   ```

   Then, you include the following where ever you want the title to appear:

   ```
   <div title-bar title="Title for this Page" />
   ```
3. You can set a watch on the title service's get() method in your sycfCtrl controller:

   ```
   $scope.$watch(function() {
       return titleService.get();
   }, function(newTitle) {
       $scope.title = newTitle;
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Turn that title tag into a function:

```
<div flex>{{Title.set()}}</div>
```

Create a service similar to the below:

```
app.factory('Title', function() {
    return {
        set: function(title) {
            title = title;
        }
    };
});
```

Then inject this Title service into each of your controllers (for your components) and use it to set the title appropriately:

```
function Test1Ctrl($scope, Page) {
    Page.setTitle('title1');
}

angular.module('sycf').controller('sycfCtrl', function($scope, Title) {
    Title.set('title goes here');
});
```

Comment: Alright so I basically solved it by just changing `$scope.title = titleService.get();` to `$scope.title = titleService;` and then in the tag I changed it from {{title}} to {{title.get()}}. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Put this is title controller
$rootScope.$on("TitleUpdate", function(title) {
    $scope.title = title;
});

// Put this in the setter of title service
$rootScope.$broadcast("TitleUpdate", title);
```